# Asp.net membership logout doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

I am trying to implement membership in my application but i have a problem.
This is my login code i am creating the ticket on login:

```
Kullanici kullanici = KullaniciProvider.KulaniciGetirEmailSifreIle(LoginControl.UserName, LoginControl.Password);
if (kullanici != null)
{
    Session["Kullanici"] = kullanici;
    string rol = "Firma";
    if (kullanici.KullaniciTipi == "Admin")
        rol = "Admin";


    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(LoginControl.UserName, true);
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new
    FormsAuthenticationTicket(
         1,
         LoginControl.UserName,
         System.DateTime.Now,
         System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
         true,
         rol,
         FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    Response.Cookies.Add(new
    HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(LoginControl.UserName, true));
}
```

This is my Global.asax file getting the roles:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
        {
            FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = (id.Ticket);
            if (!FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
            {
                //If cookie is not supported for forms authentication, then the
                //authentication ticket is stored in the URL, which is encrypted.
                //So, decrypt it
                ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(id.Ticket.Name);
            }
            // Get the stored user-data, in this case, user roles
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket.UserData))
            {
                string userData = ticket.UserData;
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                //Roles were put in the UserData property in the authentication ticket
                //while creating it
                HttpContext.Current.User =
                  new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Site.Master.When user logging out the code is not working. The user can not sign out properly

```
protected void LoginStatusGiris_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{

    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    deleteCookies();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();


}
private void deleteCookies()
{
    string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
    foreach (string cookie in cookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
}
```

I have deleted all the cookies but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void LoginStatusGiris_LoggingOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        deleteCookies();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();


    }
```

Use EventArgs instead of LoginCancelEventArgs

Comment: Can you give more specific example ?

Comment: Let me explain in this way: Your LoginStatusGiris_LoggingOut method is using LoginCancelEventArgs. Just change the LoginStatusGiris_LoggingOut with EventArgs. Like I typed as answer above.

Comment: Nope my friend I have done it but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `LoginStatusGiris LoggedOut` event instead, and clear the session and cookies like this:

```
protected void LoginStatusGiris_LoggedOut(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    deleteCookies();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}

private void deleteCookies()
{
    string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
    foreach (string cookie in cookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope this is not working unfortunetly. I am trying to redirect to login page from default page user login and then page redirects back to default page.This is working but when the user log outs i killed all the sessions cookies but the loginview still staying in the logged in template.

Comment: Are you doing any thing custom with the loginView? Can you share all the code involving the LoginView?

Comment: This is my sample project https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sljqw7iy4um7ch/AcikEksiltme.rar